# Need a tool to automatically scale text size in textbox

Tags: css, responsive-design, batch-processing, document

I need to find a feature or tool that allows me to *programmatically* create a file in which I will have a sized textbox with text that automatically scales to fit its dimensions and still be visible.

Here is an example of what it would do:
[image: Desired feature: automatic fit text size to box]

On the left side, an already sized textbox has some text. The text is too long so it goes "out" the textbox, therefore the tool would "scale" it to a size that makes it visible only in the textbox, and not outside. It could scale by changing font size, or "zoom" in any way.

I tried looking at OpenOffice Writer & Impress, Microsoft Word & Powerpoint, with no success. It seems really difficult with CSS according to the resources I could find.

Some resources I found (like [Fitty](https://rikschennink.github.io/fitty/), which is in Javascript. Not what I need, but still possible) will scale it in other manners that do not correspond my needs because they keep the text on one line, and I need them multiline...

See some wrong examples:
[image: Wrong ways to scale]

Does anyone know any tool that would have such feature?